# Find a function with the property, or prove it doesn't exist

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Today, I encountered the following problem in my research. I'd like to find a function $f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ such that 
$$
0 = \frac{d f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)}{d a}\bigg|_{c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n} \iff \forall i: 0 = \frac{d x_i}{d a}\bigg|_{c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n}
$$
Presume all functions behave nicely. I fail to find one, and I think it is impossible, but I can't see why?

Comment: Your property, as written, doesn't make much sense. What kind of a variable is $a$, and what does $c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n$ mean? Note that $f$ can only be partially differentiated with respect to its own variables $x_1$, $\ldots$, $x_n$.

Comment: I will assume that the derivative is to be evaluated at the point where $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=(c_1,\ldots,c_n)$ ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: If $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are real-valued functions of a real variable $a$, and $f$ is to be a function taking values in $\mathbb R^n$, then I believe there is such a function, but if $f$ must be real-valued then there is none. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Indeed. Also, it is a physical problem, it is safe to assume everything is in function of everything. So $x_i$ depends on $a$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Why would there be none?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Behave nicely" must mean, among other things, that $f$ has a gradient $\displaystyle(\nabla f)(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$.

This is a vector in $\mathbb R^n$ assigned to each point $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ in the domain of $f$.  There is a chain rule that says

$$
\frac{df}{da} = ((\nabla f)(x_1,\ldots, x_n))\cdot \frac d {da} (x_1,\ldots,x_n)
$$
where the product is the usual dot product of vectors.  (And this chain rule is true when $f$ "behaves nicely", as it probably would in physical applications.)

The dot product is zero if the two vectors are at right angles to each other.  That means if $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ moves as $a$ changes, in a direction at a right angle to the gradient, then $df/da$ is zero even though $(d/da)(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ may be far from zero.